# What should I do to leave Chile when I've overstayed my visa?

Tags: overstaying, chile

On 15 May, I entered Chile; my visa was for 3 months. On 10 July, I booked a ticket to go to New Zealand. I bought the ticket from LATAM Airlines for $1700 (USD).

But they didn’t let me board the flight to go to New Zealand and also they didn’t refund my money. Now, it is three months that I have been trying to get back my money, but they don’t want to give it to me unfortunately.

Now I want to leave Chile and go back to Amsterdam, my home. What should I do ?

Comment: See also the previous question [Overstaying a tourist visa in Chile, any other penalties despite a small fine?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29037/overstaying-a-tourist-visa-in-chile-any-other-penalties-despite-a-small-fine). It appears that, at minimum, you'll have to pay a fine ([this website](https://www.bizlatinhub.com/2017-chile-immigratin-law-reform/) says it's quite a large fine, while that answer indicates a small one) and will have to talk to the police, but I'm not sure of the exact procedures you'll have to follow.

Comment: I would suggest removing the complaint about LATAM, as of now the question reads as half-rant and half-question. What does it matter what you paid for a ticket to an unrelated destination?

Answer (score 6):

While you may not be a US citizen, the [US Embassy in Chile](https://cl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/entry-exit-requirements/) offers a clear directive on what to do for those who overstay:

> **If you have stayed in Chile for more than the allowed time period**, you will not be allowed to leave the country without paying a fine. This fine cannot be paid at the airport, so you should pay it before attempting to depart Chile. To pay the fine prior to your departure, you should go to the [Departamento de Extranjería](http://www.extranjeria.gob.cl/) and make an *autodenuncia* or complaint against yourself in the Sanciones office. Upon doing this, you will be told how much the fine will be, and once you pay it, you can depart Chile.
>
> If you attempt to depart Chile without paying the fine, your passport will be confiscated by the airport police, and they will give you directions on how to pay the fine. This process involves going to multiple Chilean government offices, first to find out how much the fine is, then to pay the fine, next to show that you have paid the fine, so that you can get a document indicating your passport should be returned, and lastly, to retrieve your passport. The entire process may take from several days to three weeks.

Should you need consular assistance to return to The Netherlands, here is the contact information:

Embassy of the Netherlands in Santiago
Chile Apoquindo 3500, 13th floor 
Las Condes Santiago Chile
Telephone Number: (+56) 2 2756 9200
Fax Number:  (+56) 2 2756 9226
Email: stg@minbuza.nl
Website: www.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/landen/chili

Should you not be a Dutch citizen, you may need to contact the embassy or consulate that represents your nation.